# How can I create an animation from a sequence of obj files?

Tags: animation, obj

I have a bunch of obj files of human heart, at different times.

I'd like to turn them into an animated version(so that we can see the contraction and relaxation in animation), but how can I do that?

Your answer will kindly save me from my advisor, thanks...

Comment: hmm you need to change it from one to another in matter of 1 frame? Like frame 1 is one object, frame 2 is other object? How many objects do you have? If it is like 10 objects you could just use material with alpha, frame 0 alpha of obj1 set to 0 and frame 1 set it to 1, frame to set it to 0 and repeat with other objects... (but this is possible only if you have few objects or it will take ages...) rendering each frame separately and compositing it together would take ages as well... hmm

Comment: @MikoCG It is just a single object, human heart, just captured at different timings. I cannot really understand what you are saying maybe because I lack some knowledge. I will speculate on your words, thx!

Comment: "I have a bunch of obj files" - How many obj files do you have? That's what I meant

Comment: @MikoCG Maybe 20 or something

Comment: and every obj object of heart has single textured material, multiple materials or no materials?

Comment: @MikoCG Single texture. I guess I can put just each obj file into different frame, but I am not sure whether it is possible in blender

Comment: neverming, that addon in answer will make it easy

Answer (score 2):

Looks like these add-ons can make this job:

https://blenderartists.org/t/stop-motion-obj-obj-stl-ply-sequence-importer-v2-1-1/670105

https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-import-obj-sequence-as-shape-keys-on-one-object/575402

Also, you should know, that blender has built-in modifiers, that can import *.abc sequence and *.mdd *.pc2 files (*mesh cache* and *mesh sequence cache* modifiers), so if you have an ability to get  these formats instead of obj, you should prefer it.

Comment: I'll check this out soon. Thanks for help.

Comment: Love you, I did not know there are 3rd party add-ons. Thanks, I learned a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is less than a year old, I feel as though it might be relevant to share my recent experience with solving this problem. In my particular case, I wanted to have flexibility with how I build sequences of objects and materials, so I wrote a custom script to handle loading.

```py
import bpy
from typing import List

def load_obj_files(obj_file_paths: List[str]) -> List[bpy.types.Object]:
    """Loads the obj files into memory as blender obj objects.

    Args:
        obj_file_paths (List[str]): The list of paths to obj files

    Returns:
        List[bpy.types.Object]: The loaded obj files as blender objects
    """
    objects = []
    for p in obj_file_paths:
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
        bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(
            filepath=p,
            filter_glob="*.obj;*.mtl",
            use_edges=True,
            use_smooth_groups=True,
            use_split_objects=True,
            use_split_groups=True,
            use_groups_as_vgroups=False,
            use_image_search=True,
            split_mode="ON",
            axis_forward="Z",
            axis_up="Y",
        )

        # Selected object is the first one, append to our cache
        objects.append(bpy.context.selected_objects[0])
    return objects


def build_animation_from_obj_files(all_obj_objects: List[bpy.types.Object]):
    """Loads a sequence of loaded blender objects and adds them to a given animation

    Args:
        all_obj_objects (List[bpy.types.Object]): The obj objects loaded from memory
    """
    # Set the starting frame to 0
    obj_frame_start = 0
    obj_frame_end = len(all_obj_objects) - 1

    # Set the scene frames in the UI.
    bpy.context.scene.frame_start = obj_frame_start
    bpy.context.scene.frame_end = obj_frame_end

    # Now, the high level idea here is simple. For each frame, we need to set EVERY object
    # as "invisible" on render except "frame". So if we have 500 frames worth of objects
    # we would then iterate through all the frames, set every object's "hide_render" field
    # to "True" and then just this frame's "hide_render" is set to "False", showing ONLY
    # this frame on the render.
    for frame in range(obj_frame_end):
        # VERY IMPORTANT. We need to set the frame here to ensure that the proper frame
        # is active when we set the frame states
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)

        # Now, we have to iterate through ALL frames to add the keyframe for this scene
        # frame.
        for i, ob in enumerate(all_obj_objects):
            # If our iteration has reached our designated frame, mark it as visible
            if i == frame:
                ob.hide_viewport = ob.hide_render = False
                ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_viewport")
                ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render")
            # Otherwise, set it to invisible
            else:
                ob.hide_viewport = ob.hide_render = True
                ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_viewport")
                ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render")
```

This is reasonably barebones, so it may not be robust enough to solve every type of problem, but, it will load the requisite resources and then allow you to run the animation between all of the keyframes. This system just needs to be copy-pasted into the blender "Scripts" window and then you just need to click run and it should work to at least get you started.

Note however that you will need to add an invocation for it and to also load the file paths in the script yourself. This was only tested with Blender 3.2, so things may change between versions.

I am 100% sure that there is likely a better way to do this, but if you just need something that will probably work, this will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I made a video tutorial how to make it without any plugin https://youtu.be/KRxDyloJRYU

-1 because of someone who don't like youtube, in the comment below. But don't afraid. It's working.

Comment: Please consider [expanding this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/280707/edit) to be a complete answer with the details here. If for some reason the video goes away, then there is nothing for future visitors to see. [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/387343) may be removed if not further improved.