# Save animation that contains multiple objects as fbx

Tags: animation, objects, .fbx

I have a folder containing multiple .obj and .mtl files.
They represent the mesh and the color of a certain material for different time steps.

I managed to create an animation with the following script:

```
import bpy
import os
from typing import List


def load_objects_from_obj_files(directory):
    # Create an empty list to store the imported objects
    imported_objects = []

    # Create a set to keep track of the previously imported object names
    imported_object_names = set()

    # Get a list of all .obj files in the directory
    obj_files = [file for file in os.listdir(os.path.normpath(directory)) if file.endswith('.obj')]

    # Iterate over each .obj file and import it into Blender
    for obj_file in obj_files:
        obj_filepath = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(directory, obj_file))
        bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=obj_filepath, axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')

        # Get the newly imported objects by comparing their names and skip duplicates
        new_objects = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects if obj.name not in imported_object_names]

        # Append the imported objects to the list
        imported_objects.extend(new_objects)

        # Update the set of imported object names
        imported_object_names.update(obj.name for obj in new_objects)

    return imported_objects


# This function was posted on stackoverflow (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237006/how-can-i-create-an-animation-from-a-sequence-of-obj-files)
def build_animation_from_obj_files(all_obj_objects: List[bpy.types.Object]):
    """Loads a sequence of loaded blender objects and adds them to a given animation

    Args:
        all_obj_objects (List[bpy.types.Object]): The obj objects loaded from memory
    """
    # Set the starting frame to 0
    obj_frame_start = 0
    obj_frame_end = len(all_obj_objects) - 1

    # Set the scene frames in the UI.
    bpy.context.scene.frame_start = obj_frame_start
    bpy.context.scene.frame_end = obj_frame_end

    # Now, the high level idea here is simple. For each frame, we need to set EVERY object
    # as "invisible" on render except "frame". So if we have 500 frames worth of objects
    # we would then iterate through all the frames, set every object's "hide_render" field
    # to "True" and then just this frame's "hide_render" is set to "False", showing ONLY
    # this frame on the render.
    for frame in range(obj_frame_end):
        # VERY IMPORTANT. We need to set the frame here to ensure that the proper frame
        # is active when we set the frame states
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)

        # Now, we have to iterate through ALL frames to add the keyframe for this scene
        # frame.
        for i, ob in enumerate(all_obj_objects):
            # If our iteration has reached our designated frame, mark it as visible
            if i == frame:
                ob.hide_viewport = ob.hide_render = False
                ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_viewport")
                ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render")
            # Otherwise, set it to invisible
            else:
                ob.hide_viewport = ob.hide_render = True
                ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_viewport")
                ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render")


# Path to the directory containing the .obj files
directory = r'C:\Users\username\obj_files'

# Create objects from .obj files
imported_objects = load_objects_from_obj_files(directory)


# Call the function to build the animation
build_animation_from_obj_files(imported_objects)
```

The animation is working properly in Blender, but I only see one of the objects when I save it as .fbx file.
I would like to know if there is a way to save the whole animation as a .fbx file. I tried many different ways (chatGPT) and no luck. I am starting to think that this approach that I have is not the most suitable for it.
What is your advice?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think object visibility is an exportable property to begin with.

If you want to use that in another software, you should animate in that software instead.

---

Concerning the export issue itself:

I bet the issue here is that you export the objects with "*Selected Objects*" enabled in the export options. The issue is: in Blender, you can't select hidden objects. So I bet the only object you get in the resulting FBX is the one that was visible at the frame you were when exporting.

The simplest solution to that is probably to add one frame in your animation (frame zero for simplicity) where all objects are visible. And export from that frame.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: There's the votes buttons and the answer acceptation checkmark if you want ;)

Comment: Sorry, I thought my comment was not posted because I wanted to elaborate it (not just say 'Thanks for your comment'). I haven't found a solution for this yet. As you said, fbx only saves the selected object and I don't have the "Selected Objects" enabled.
But your solution doesn't allow me to do the animation that I want.

Comment: There aren't many solutions when the data you wish for isn't supported. You need to give more information then. In which software will you import this animation? Do you have to do the animation in Blender and not in the target software?

Comment: The end goal is to export a fbx file to Unity 3D. I have multiple .obj files that represent an animation. I would like to merge all these obj files and show them in Unity as a single object.

Comment: I haven't used Unity in a long time but I am pretty sure you can do such animation in Unity. You can even program it entirely and have no keyframes involved at all.

Comment: Thanks. I thinks that what I will try to do. After all, my objects have the same number of vertices. Which makes me think it will be easy to do it. But I can't not avoid the fact that I have multiple .obj files and .mtl in a particular folder.

Comment: You can always import the .blend file you made into Unity and work from there.